# Getting the correct contact name by phone number

Tags: android

I am trying to get the correct contact name from a phone number to display it into a `ListView`.

But I am getting every time only the same Contact Name for all phone numbers...

Here is my code:

```
private String getContactName(String string){
    String name=null;

    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

    if(cur.getCount()>0){
        while(cur.moveToNext()){
            String id=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

    }
    return name;
}


public void onClick(View v)
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null);

    int indexBody=cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
    int indexAddr=cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);

    //  int indexAddr = Integer.parseInt(getContactName(Integer.toString(cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS ))));

    //getContactName(Integer.toString(indexAddr));
    ////

    if(indexBody<0||!cursor.moveToFirst())return;

    smsList.clear();

    do
    {
        //String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );
        String str="Sender: "+getContactName(cursor.getString(indexAddr))+"\n"+cursor.getString(indexBody);
        smsList.add(str);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());


    ListView smsListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
    registerForContextMenu(smsListView);

    smsListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,smsList));
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

I can't find where is my error... and only get the same name for all senders numbers.

Thank you

Comment: When you get your names you don't moveToFirst your cursor. So, you're on the last one and exit immediately, getting only the last name (which won't necessarily be in any alphabetical order).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code for your function.

```
private String getContactName(String phoneNumber)
{
    String name = null;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
        Uri.encode(phoneNumber)), new String[]{ PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
    if(cur != null){
        try{
            if(cur.getCount() > 0){
                if(cur.moveToFirst()){
                    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            }
        }
        finally{
            cur.close();
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```